# Is it possible in JS to dynamically set the property to be destructured?

Tags: javascript

## Challenge

Here's two possible states of many:

```js
const state1 = {
  Url: 'google.com/store'
}

const state2 = {
  Url: 'google.com/store',
  Link: 'yahoo.com/videos'
}
```

Here's an exemplary function I would like to call in its current form:

```js
const logUrl = ({ Url }) => console.log(`This is the ${Url}´);
```

However, if I want to use this function with both states (I always know there is a url coming, just not always under which property), which allows me to:

- destructure the function with `({ Url })` for state1
- destructure the function with `({ Link })` for state2
- without have multiple copies of the same function just with different input parameters
- still using JS destructuring

## Attempts

I can obviously get it to work using something like

```js
const logUrl = prop => obj => console.log(`This is the ${obj[prop]}`)
```

but this doesn't satisfy the "still using JS destructuring" part (required by many internal APIs).

So I though about

```js
const logUrl = prop => ({ url = this[prop] }) => console.log(`This is the ${url}`)
```

but sadly this doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas if this is even possible and if so, how to do it in JS?

Comment: Why not just grab `{ Url, Link }` and see which one has a value? There's no API that requires destructuring; that's a linting preference--and it's not one that always makes sense, like when you don't know what's coming.

Comment: Thanks for your comment dave. You are right in the sense that the APIs don't require it in the sense that they cannot be changed, but at the moment much of the testing and functional library utilizes destructuring of ({ Url )} and I just ran into the situation that the state is filling up with more "link" properties (at which point both props are filled), so was simply wondering if there is a solution without removing destructuring from most properties.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do this:

```
const logUrl = ({ Url, Link }) => console.log(`This is the ${Link || Url}´);
```

Why are you making things so hard on yourself by enforcing all these useless semantic rules (must use destructuring) when the logic is all that matters?

For the record, no, you can't dynamically destructure an object without using additional logic.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Adam, the solution you mention is cool but not doesn't really work for state2, where both values are filled (i.e. the state is filled with more url properties I want to choose from). I'll see if I can work around destructuring without having to change so much about the current function library (currently utilizing destructuring).